# Java inner interfaces as return types

Tags: java, generics, method-chaining

I'm learning Java and recently came across the following piece of code that is working properly, but I don't understand why:

```
public class ExecutionChain<Result> {

    Parametriezed1<Result>  classMethod1() {
        return this::method1;
    }

    Parametriezed2<Result> method1() {
        return this::method2;
    }

    Result method2(Result result) {
        return result;
    }

    interface Parametriezed1<Result> {
        Parametriezed2 method1();
    }

    interface Parametriezed2<Result> {
        Result method2(Result result);
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain:

- why `method1` seems to be overriding `Parametriezed2 method1()` without `ExecutionChain` implementing `Parametriezed1`
- why it is ok to call `this::method1` in spite of the fact that neither `method1` nor `method2` returns `Parametriezed1` type?

I would be more than grateful for some documentation for the principles that were used here.

Comment: *FYI:* That code is **bad**. The return type of `method1()` in `Parametriezed1` is returning a **raw** generic. *Very bad!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both interfaces only contain one method, that makes them `FunctionalInterface`s, meaning a single function with the correct signature can implement them.

The methods returning the interfaces return methods with the correct signature.

The class itself doesn't implement the interfaces; to do that, the methods would need to have the same name as well. Think of it as returning a subset of the class' methods, maybe.

It is a pretty convoluted piece of code if you ask me.